# How can I retain all index levels from 2 multi-index series in pandas multiply?

Tags: python, pandas

In my application I am multiplying two Pandas Series which both have multiple index levels. Sometimes, a level contains only a single unique value, in which case I don't get all the index levels from both Series in my result.

To illustrate the problem, let's take two series:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1,2,3,4]])
s1.index.names = ['A', 'B']
A  B
1  1   -2.155463
   2   -0.411068
   3    1.041838
   4    0.016690
```

```
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], [1,2,3,4]])
s2.index.names = ['C', 'B']
C  B
a  1    0.043064
   2   -1.456251
   3    0.024657
   4    0.912114
```

Now, if I multiply them, I get the following:

```
s1.mul(s2)
A  B
1  1   -0.092822
   2    0.598618
   3    0.025689
   4    0.015223
```

While my desired result would be

```
A  C  B
1  a  1   -0.092822
      2    0.598618
      3    0.025689
      4    0.015223
```

How can I keep index level C in the multiplication?

I have so far been able to get the right result as shown below, but would much prefer a neater solution which keeps my code more simple and readable.

```
s3 = s2.mul(s1).to_frame()
s3['C'] = 'a'
s3.set_index('C', append=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = s2.unstack(level=0).mul(s1, level=1, axis=0).stack().reorder_levels(['A','C','B'])
print (s)
A  C  B
1  a  1    0.827482
      2   -0.476929
      3   -0.473209
      4   -0.520207
dtype: float64
```